# How do you unzip a zipped observable in RxJs?

Tags: rxjs

I would like to "unzip" a zipped Observable, I searched for something akin to the "Spread" operator but it's just not there, I tried to make my own unzip but I have to hardcode the length of the zip. Is there a way to do this without hardcoding it

```js
(p =>
//[0,1,2] is hardcoded.
  rxjs.zip(...[0, 1, 2].map(i => p.pipe(rxjs.map(a => a[i]))))
)(
  rxjs.zip(rxjs.range(3, 4), rxjs.range(9, 4), rxjs.range(124, 7))
).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Zip combines multiple Observables into one.  For "unzip" do you want to split a single Observable back into multiple Observables?

Comment: @DavidBraun correct, the problem is that you have to consume the observable to know its length.
In a way, I want to "transpose" an observable of arrays into arrays of observables. aka get `rxjs.range(3, 4)` back

Comment: actually now that I think of it, you only have to consume the first element to know how many observables you want to release

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you just want to flatten the zip result into separate elements down the stream.

This can be easily achieved with an additional `mergeMap`, for example:

```
zip(of(1), of(2), of(3))
.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Will output `[1, 2, 3]`, however if you add a merge map to unwrap the array, like this:

```
zip(of(1), of(2), of(3))
.pipe(mergeMap(e => of(...e)))
.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

the output will be:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: more like I want to transpose it back. Not flatten it.